# Center JOptionPane icon

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have a JOptionPane with a lot of text on it... which stretches it taller than wide. This causes the icon to appear to "float" up high in the window.

Is there a way to "center" the icon?

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ProgManager.getMainWindow(),
    ProgManager.getMainWindow().getAboutBoxPane(), 
        Res.getString("title.about"), JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
            ProgRes.getImageIcon(ProgRes.MAIN_IMAGE));
```

I'd like this:

[image]

To appear more like:

[image]

without having to modify the image.

Comment: @RafaEl the icon on the left side of the window is centered vertically in the bottom image.

Comment: I don't know if that's possible using `JOptionPane`. Prefer writing your own dialog, it's not that hard and you can order the `components` however you want to

Comment: @Markus I was afraid of that... was hoping for a quick change...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Wrap the image a icon in a `JLabel` and wrap that label in a `JPanel` with a `GridBagLayout` (this layout will keep the image/label centered).
2. Create another `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout`, adding the image panel to the `WEST` and the text component to the `CENTER`
3. Add just that `JPanel` from 2 to to the `JOptionPane.`

---

Example

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestImageCenter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(TestImageCenter.class.getResource("/resources/images/ooooo.png"));
        JLabel iconLabel = new JLabel(icon);
        JPanel iconPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        iconPanel.add(iconLabel);

        JPanel textPanel= new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            textPanel.add(new JLabel("Hello, StackOverfkow"));
        }

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(textPanel);
        mainPanel.add(iconPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mainPanel, "Center Image Dialog", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```